# Jest implicit type checking on expected value

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Suppose I have this function

```
function myFunction(): { foo: number; bar: string } {
  return { foo: 1, bar: 'bar' };
}
```

and I want to test it using jest.

```
it('myFunction', () => {
   expect(myFunction()).toStrictEqual({ foo: 1, bar: 2 /*oops wrong type!*/ });
});
```

And this will compile despite `bar` being passed as a `number` instead of `string` such as defined in `myFunction`.

This is a shame because this could be caught at compile-time instead of run-time.

I could also write

```
it('test', () => {
  expect(myFunction()).toStrictEqual<ReturnType<typeof myFunction>>({
    foo: 1,
    bar: 1, /* this time, the mistake is caught at compile-time :) */
  });
});
```

but this is verbose, redundant, and a pain when using `Promise`.

I am looking for a trick to implicitely do this. **Is there a helper that would allow to type check on the returned or resolved type by default?**

Comment: You can infer a type like `const result = myFunction()`, this will make it easier. What problem do you have with promises, is that about `resolves`? I guess this wasn't done because doing this by default causes more problems than solves. This will become more complicated with `expect.any`, etc. And the real problem is how ir works with the rest of API like `not`.

Comment: Infering with an intermediate variable is a good compromise, thanks